# Replacing a particular pattern using gsub in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching, gsub

I have a question regarding the `gsub` function in R. I have the following vector:

```
a=c('2.1','3.1.1.1','70','-940','10.1.1')
```

where I want to apply `gsub` function to extract only the following:

```
b=c('2.1','3.1.1.1','10.1.1')
```

Here 'b' is the section numbers of a certain document. 
So essentially I want to replace `c('70','-940')` and get 'b'. Since,I am a newbie in R,I am not sure about the pattern to enter into `gsub` for this particular case.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `gsub` does not change the length of a vector so it's probably not the right function in this case. How do you know what you want to remove? Are you storing values in another vector? Do you know the indices you want to remove?

Comment: Since I am only looking for the section numbers,I know what kind of  pattern they have and these two dont fall in the required pattern.Could you suggest which function I should use?Also,I am wondering,whether those two values can be replaced by space using gsub,so that the length of the vector remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing here is to match based on the period and just use `grepl` to create a logical extraction index rather than `gsub`:

```
b <- a[grepl("^([[:digit:]]+\\.)+", a)]
b
## [1] "2.1"     "3.1.1.1" "10.1.1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..this has solved a part of my problem.Another problem is,say I have a vector:a=c("-70....","90","1.1.1","23.1").Using your methodology i  get the following vector:a=c("-70....","1.1.1","23.1"),which is incorrect.Can you please suggest a way to resolve this problem

Comment: @SBS What's your rule for determining what is correct and incorrect?

Comment: There is no such defined rule,but I know that section numbers lie between 1 and 10 and could be of the form "10.1" or "10.2.1" etc,and high digits like 70 are definitely incorrect

Comment: @SBS In order to create a regex (or any other) substitution strategy, you have to be able to define what should be included or not included. Otherwise how would one possibly solve this problem?

Comment: I know how the sections and sub-sections look like e.g. section number"1.2.3" or "10.2" or "6." These are the patterns I am looking for,The rest is incorrect.

Comment: @SBS See edit, which should work for your new example vector.